# Renewing MDM APNS certificate but forgot which Apple ID used

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, mdm

The problem is that a customer cannot trace the APPLE ID used to generate the MDM APNS certificate, and it is about to expire! They need to log in to https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/ to renew it.

According to Apple, if the cert expires, all devices will have to be re-enrolled!

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not going to be a way around this. If they have an Enterprise account it is likely (hopefully) they kept things vanilla and the Agent's account was used to create the MDM/APNs cert.